# If $X$ is a random variable satisfying $P[|X| < \infty]=1$ there exist a bounded random variable $Y$ that approximates it well

Tags: probability-theory

If $X$ is a random variable satisfying $P[|X| < \infty]=1$, then show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exist a bounded random variable  $Y$ such that 
\begin{align*}
P[X \neq Y] < \epsilon
\end{align*}

This is what I tried

I know that a random variable $Y$ is bounded if for all $\omega$ $|Y(\omega)| \le K$ for some constant $K$ independent of $\omega$.

For some time I thought maybe I need to use triangle inequality but that direction didn't work.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $A=\{\omega:|X(\omega)|<\infty\}$. Define $A_{n}=\{\omega:|X(\omega)|\leq n\}$. Then $\{A_{n}\}$ is an increasing sequence of events, and $A_{n}\uparrow A$ as $n\to\infty$. Therefore $\mathbb{P}(A_{n})\uparrow\mathbb{P}(A)$.

Therefore for an $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_{\epsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A_{N_{\epsilon}})>\mathbb{P}(A)-\epsilon=1-\epsilon$. Define

$$
Y(\omega)=X(\omega)\textbf{1}_{\{|X(\omega)|\leq N_{\epsilon}\}}.
$$
Then $\mathbb{P}(Y=X)\geq 1-\epsilon$.